# SSRS and Linked Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, linked-server

For many years we've had a reporting database that we have written our SSRS reports out of, which includes some linked servers.  The linked servers are set up on the SQL instance where reporting services lives, as well as the main databases we use to report out of.  We've decide to split off reporting service from the main server, and give it its own house.

I've setup SQL 2014 along with reporting services, and published my reports over there instead.  All of the 'non-linked' reports work fine.  However all the reports that reference a linked server (that used to work on the main server) now fail with the following error in the log file:

> Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.

I thought maybe I needed to set up the linked servers on the new RS SQL server to get this to work.  I had assumed that it would pass the entire query (including the linked part) over to the data source specified and my primary server would run it and return the data.  Nevertheless, I set up the exact same linked servers on the new reporting services box... but still receive the same error.

All these reports worked just fine on the original server, however they all seem to be having issues on the new server no matter what linked server they are connecting to.

I am at a loss, and would love any ideas you guys may have.

Server A:
   Main Data Source.  This server contains the majority of our data and also housed our Reporting Services.  This server has links to several other SQL servers that I was able to openquery to, and join the data to our main data source.  We have many published reports that utilize the linked servers and have historically provided no issues.

Server B:
   New SSRS box.  This new server was set up in an attempt to off-load all of our reporting needs to another box thereby freeing up any resources required to run reports and SSIS packages.  I took all of our existing reports and published them to the new server as-is.  Initially I didn't think I would need to recreate the linked servers on this box, since those requests would be going to my main data source (Server A).  I've tried both with, and without the linked servers existing on Server B, but get the same results.  When the linked servers DID exist on Server B, I was able to query them directly with no errors.  The services on Server B are running under the same credentials as those on Server A.

Comment: The Linked Servers should only need to be on the SQL Server where the report connection points to, not the SQL Server where the SSRS systems databases are served from. Is your main reporting database on a new server, too? If so, did you build the Linked Servers there from scratch, or were they scripted from the old server? I feel like they may be missing a setting.

Comment: First test the linked server in SSMS (i.e. select through it) to try and isolate the problem. It might just be the linked server. If an SSMS test works, check your authentication settings in the SSRS source. This could also be a double hop issue. Can you edit your question and explain the before and after server setup (ie. Server A does this, Server B does this), as well as what kind of authentication you are using for each connection (SSRS data source and linked server)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did some more digging and found my resolution. So the data sources have always been using the end users credentials to run the reports. On the old server, the linked servers use a hard coded SQL account to make the connection. This works fine so long as it is all on one server. However, when running from a secondary server it appears that this scenario will not work. Instead, I found that if I make the data source use the 'same' hard coded SQL account and the linked server to make the connection to Server A, the linked servers work fine.